# Change Camel's basic /camel url

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Issue:

- I would need to change the basic /camel url which camel uses by default, but when i try to change it in application.yml nothing happens to it.
- Would like to keep other systems intact without changing their urls, from what they already have (would require quiet a bit of work in back-end systems)

Current URL: http://localhost:8080/camel/hello

Desired URL: http://localhost:8080/service/hello

Checked links which are NOT working for me:

[Link1](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/servlet-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_servlet_mapping_context-path)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961716/how-to-use-the-context-path-in-camel-routes)

[Link3](https://github.com/astefanutti/spring-boot-camel-rest-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/application.yml)

EG: application.yml

```
 camel:
  springboot:
    name: CamelRestContext
  component:
    servlet:
      mapping:
        enabled: true
        context-path: /service
```

Comment: have you tried `/service/*` (with wild card, analogous to default value `/camel/*`)?

Comment: yes tried /service/* and /service  and /service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this way works:

```
camel:
  springboot:
    name: RestDSLContext
  servlet:
    mapping:
      context-path: /service/*
  rest:
    context-path: /service
```

Comment: In most of the other posts `camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path` is the answer, which does not work. For me, i just needed the `camel.servlet.mapping.context-path` setting, the `rest` and `springboot` part was not necessary. Thank you very much for that hint! Still strange is, that after starting the app, the context-path is still empty while logging: `CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet, contextPath=]`

Comment: Yes for whatever reason when using `yaml` u need to define the `URL/ component`. As for the `contextPath` being empty, that can be changed also, but then that `contextPath` will be added also to the `URL`, so i found it easier to leave it empty.